# Applying Twitter Bootstrap theme to Django website

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

How would I go about installing a Twitter Bootstrap theme such as http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ to an existing Django website? I'm quite new to all of this, so I'm a little lost as to where I should begin. I'm well acquainted with Javascript, CSS, and JQuery, but I'm not too familiar with Django.

I've looked into demo projects such as https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit, but I'm not sure where I should begin for an existing project.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `css` into the `static` folder and call the `css` in the html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstraptheme/css/styles.css">
```